# Integral sinus in C#

Tags: c#, integer, trigonometry

I want to implement perfomance-sensitive integral calculations in C#. I was told that function int Sin(int angle) that returns a value between -256 and 255 is useful in this situation, since I don't need it to be exact. Is there a good implementation of such a function that I can use, or some algorithm that I can implement?

Comment: It's just a lookup table. Just create the table using the built-in sin function at startup, and write your function to lookup into that table.  Here is a question which is basically the same, your function would just take an int rather than a double: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088194/fast-sin-cos-using-a-pre-computed-translation-array - this answer also uses unsafe code to get a bit of extra speed, but you can just use a normal array if you don't want unsafe code.

Comment: I think that this comment is actually a perfect answer to my question. Thanks!

Comment: @JamesGaunt post this as an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a lookup table. Just create the table using the built-in sin function at startup, and write your function to lookup into that table. Here is a question which is basically the same, your function would just take an int rather than a double:

[Fast Sin/Cos using a pre computed translation array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088194/fast-sin-cos-using-a-pre-computed-translation-array)

This answer also uses unsafe code to get a bit of extra speed, but you can just use a normal array if you don't want unsafe code